# $http post with angularjs to datastore

Tags: angularjs, python-2.7, google-app-engine, http-post, webapp2

Trying to send a simple post to the  GAE datastore but I am missing a line or 2 of code (where you see '##?') in the **main.py** to complete the 'POST'. Not sure what exactly. In dev tools everything seems 200 OK in controller and the datastore shows a new entry has been made but the actual data does not come through. Just the column with empty fields. `BaseTemplateHandler` inherits all that `webapp2.Requesthandler` stuff

**Projects.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Project(ndb.Model):
    Description = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.insert = function() {

      $scope.projects = [];
      var x = $scope.info

      var payload = {
            texto: x
      }

      $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/#/",
            data: payload
        }).then(function(response) {
          $scope.projects.push(payload);
          console.log(response);
        }, function(response) {

      });
    };
```

**main.py**

```
from models.projects import Project
p = Project()

class IndexHandler(BaseTemplateHandler):
    @classmethod
    def route(cls):
        """
        name: index, template: /
        """
        return webapp2.Route('/', handler=cls, name='index')

    def get(self):
        context = {}
        self.render_response('index.html', **context)

    def post(self):
        ##? 

        p.Description=self.request.get("texto")
        p.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: What's the output of `self.request.get("texto")` ?

Comment: Show us the `Project` class that you imported.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's the user's input from `<textarea name="texto" ng-model="info"></textarea>`

Comment: ok, what's the output of the above code? ie, `print self.request.get("texto", None)`, displays what?

Comment: try `d = dict(self.request.POST.items()); print d.get("texto", None)`

Comment: If it's None, then try to print the dict...

Comment: @AvinashRaj not sure how to print when I'm in main.py. New to, and using pycharm if you mean debugging in an IDE like pycharm

Comment: @Kekito I've updated

Comment: See the server logs..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123447/discussion-between-colin-dev256-and-avinash-raj).